# Explain this loop, please: for i in l: l.remove(i)

Tags: python

**Example:**

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

for i in l:
    print i,l
    l.remove(i)
```

**Returns:**

```
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
3 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
5 [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
7 [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
9 [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 0]
```

So why is there only 5 spins? I expect it to turn 10 times. 
Can someone explain it to me step by step?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12840897/748858

Comment: @Pol: Yet the reasons for the behaviour are exactly the same.

Comment: @mgilson, but you showed duplicate for sure. And explanation is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice how the printed number jumps over one number in the list? That is because, i points to a position in the list and once you delete `i` list "shifts" one position to the left and than when `i` is incremented, it in fact moves two positions to the right. So after the fifth iteration you would be in the position to the right of `0` or out of the list.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear.

Comment: @Pol try to figure out for yourself why only the odd numbers are printed and then try reading my answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found good explanation in older question?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is independent to programming language used (in this case Python) and  occurs when you delete items from a collection while iterating on it. In this example, after each loop iteration, an index to the current item in collection is increased by 1 automatically to point to the next item; when you delete an item, items shift left by one, missing one of the items.

One way to prevent this situation is to traverse the list in reverse order.

```
for i in reversed(l):
    print( i,l)
    l.remove(i)
```

which generates:

```
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4 [1, 2, 3, 4]
3 [1, 2, 3]
2 [1, 2]
1 [1]
```

Comment: Or you can iterate on copy of list like this: `for i in l[:]: l.remove(i)`